# I am trying to importxml from ENSEMBL using xpath copied from Chrome, but it is not working

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath

I want to use google sheet's IMPORTXML to extract the gene name (SLC3A1) and ensembl ID (ENSG00000138079) from this URL: http://asia.ensembl.org/Multi/Search/Results?q=SLC3A1;site=ensembl

I tried copying xpath from Chrome and also tried deriving it on my own step by step, but I am only getting a #NA.

My xpath: `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span`

From Chrome: `//*[@id="solr_content"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a`

The idea is to extract gene name and ID to google sheets for any gene name I supply.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath worked on Firefox and should work on Chrome too since it's standard XPath.

```
$x('//a[ancestor::div[@id="solr_content"] and @class="table_toplink" and .="SLC3A1 (Human Gene)"]/following-sibling::div/span[@class="id"]/text()')
```

Result

```
Array [ #text
 ]
​
0: #text "ENSG00000138079"
```

Comment: does not work...

Comment: @player0 sorry for the comment. Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `#N/A` error due to `importxml` (or any other import) formula does not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can test this always by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be usually imported into google sheets

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did not know this.